Cant find uuid in org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes, String = unspecified
I am facing the issue where one of the column in postgre table is of uuid and I am generating new column in pyspark which is of type string. Though I have specified the property StringType = unspecified still it is throwing the error thecol is of type uuid but expression is of type text/string
I have tried to cast it to Stringtype and given the postgre JDBC property
